# Testcontainers MS SQL Server Module stays in a loop and never enters the test

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, testcontainers, mssql-jdbc

I'm writting a JUnit4 test case with the following:

```
@Rule
public MSSQLServerContainer mssqlserver = new MSSQLServerContainer().acceptLicense();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
   url = mssqlserver.getJdbcUrl();
}
@Test
public void someTestMethod() {
...
```

But it hangs a long time and then this exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is started, but cannot be accessed by (JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:51772), please check container logs

What's wrong?

I'm using these dependencies:

```
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.16.3"
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mssqlserver:1.16.3"
```

Comment: Can you please share the container logs?

Comment: @OlegŠelajev here: https://pastebin.com/BypzAR3Z

Comment: can you add the logging config like herehttps://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/logging_config/  to declutter the log?

Comment: @OlegŠelajev here: https://pastebin.com/K6QMLp5d

Comment: It seems you did not share the full log. Are you by chance using an M1 laptop? What happens when you start the MSSQL image directly with Docker?

Comment: @OlegŠelajev I've got the same issue on an amd64 laptop. The mssql container starts up fine and I can connect to it from a different JDBC client. But testcontainers cannot connect to it. Container logs: https://pastebin.com/06L9kv2U.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a fix on the way [1]. I had to use the workaround of

```
      .withUrlParam("trustServerCertificate", "true")
```

mentioned there with testcontainers 1.16.3.

[1] https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/5032